# Grand Canyon AL SL frame size - S vs M

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, bike-fit

Checked [Grand Canyon](https://www.canyon.com/en-lt/mtb/grand-canyon/) frame sizes and can't decide which one is more suitable for me: S or M. My height is 170cm while S frame recommended height is 162-172cm and M is 172-182cm. S frame comes with 27.5" tyres but I want 29" which comes with M. What would you recommend?

Comment: These type of product recommendations and size or fit questions don't work well for stackexchange. You might want to take the [tour]...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to depend on your preferred riding position and on the ratio of your torso to leg length. Without being able to test ride, it's very hard to know for sure. If you like feeling a bit more stretched out horizontally then go for the M. If you like a bit more upright compact sitting position, then probably the S.

Comment: Also its more likely a small frame will suit if you ride tight, technical tracks vs large frame if you ride fire roads and wide open trails. But as said, no one can tell without test rides.